# JAP setFlushMode(COMMIT) in play framework do not works

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I want to deactivated the flush execution after a NamedQuery with a getResultList. But setting the setFlushMode(COMMIT) not change happened, the flush is executed anyway. Why?

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select name from ticket where age=?").setFlushMode(COMMIT);
query.setParameter(1, year).setFlushMode(COMMIT);
List<Object> tickets = query.getResultList();
```

Stack trace continuos to call execute the flush...

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Version is 4.3.11

Comment: Try the latest, as others (https://thorben-janssen.com/flushmode-in-jpa-and-hibernate/) mention that hibernate will not flush with any query in version 5 and 6. JPA doesn't require it to do anything but flush on commit - but it is and can flush any other time it wants. In this case, you are executing a native SQL query that must go to the database. Since an EntityManager is transactional, in order for your query to see any of the changes made in the current context, those changes would have to be flushed first.

Comment: I noticed, in the debug callbacks that the flush is prompted right by the execution of the getResultList regardless of whether it is a named query or native. Is it possible that there is no way to avoid flush?